# Div Not Taking Up Full Space

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, styling, semantic-ui-react

### The Problem

I'm having an issue where a max-width is being set on my div from somewhere but I'm not sure where it is as I have checked the styling package that I'm using (Semantic UI) as well as my own internal styles and I am not able to find the place where it is derived from (As shown in image 1, it is in a style tag, but that is only the compiled Semantic UI code as seen in image 2).
(Image 1)

[image: Styling Shown]

(Image 2)

[image: Semantic UI Compiled]

Because of the issue shown, this is what shows inside of the app

[image: Width Issue In-App View]

### Expected Behavior

This is what the expected behavior is: (It takes up the whole space instead of being restricted)

[image: Expected Behavior]

### Code

App.css

```
html,
body,
.app {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}

/* SidePanel.js */
.menu {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

/* Messages.js */
.messages {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* MessageForm.js */
.message__form {
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 320px !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 1em;
  z-index: 200;
}

.emoijpicker {
  position: absolute;
}

/* Message.js */
.message__self {
  border-left: 2px solid orange;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.message__image {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Messages.js (Some parts not included due to relevancy)

```
import { Segment, Comment } from "semantic-ui-react";
...

  render() {
    // prettier-ignore
    const { messagesRef, messages, channel, user, numUniqueUsers, searchTerm, searchResults, searchLoading, privateChannel, isChannelStarred, typingUsers, messagesLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <MessagesHeader
          channelName={this.displayChannelName(channel)}
          numUniqueUsers={numUniqueUsers}
          handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}
          searchLoading={searchLoading}
          isPrivateChannel={privateChannel}
          handleStar={this.handleStar}
          isChannelStarred={isChannelStarred}
        />

        <Segment>
          <Comment.Group className="messages">
            {this.displayMessageSkeleton(messagesLoading)}
            {searchTerm
              ? this.displayMessages(searchResults)
              : this.displayMessages(messages)}
            {this.displayTypingUsers(typingUsers)}
            <div ref={node => (this.messagesEnd = node)} />
          </Comment.Group>
        </Segment>

        <MessageForm
          messagesRef={messagesRef}
          currentChannel={channel}
          currentUser={user}
          isPrivateChannel={privateChannel}
          getMessagesRef={this.getMessagesRef}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { setUserPosts }
)(Messages);
```

Comment: have you tried to override the css

Comment: I'd tried on other classes but I didn't think of overriding on the class that the max-width is on until you mentioned overriding the css. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As godfather suggested in the comments, I tried an override on the .ui class and I got the expected behavior with this addition to the App.css file:

App.css

```
...
.ui {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
...
```